# Jquery datatable searching is not working

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

i am using jQuery Datatable 1.10.

Everything works great it binds the data in grid but when i try to implement search it is not working.

My code for search is here :-

```
 $('#search-date').change(function () {
        alert(this.value);
        table.column([3]).search($(this).val()).draw(); //Here table is instance of datatable.
    });
```

Alert is called but it does not show the value in grid.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: which data source option are you using ?

Comment: i am using ajax to fetch data from web service @FrebinFrancis

Comment: Which language are you using ?

Comment: have you got any console errors mate..??

Comment: I am using C# @FrebinFrancis

Comment: no there is not any console error @Outlooker

Comment: Can you please update your question with Server side code for retrieve the  List ?

Comment: Does `table.api().column([3]).search($(this).val()).draw();` by chance work?

Comment: Your code is valid. Please post your DataTable initialization code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the DataTable in other language like

```
var table = $('#inventario').DataTable({
    "language": {
        "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/i18n/Spanish.json"
    }
});
```

You need remove the language feature like this

```
 var table = $('#inventario').DataTable();
```

After, you need change the "oLanguage" property http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/i18n

Answer (score 0):

If there are no errors in the console and correct json is sent in the response, look at the [draw](https://www.datatables.net/manual/server-side) param under "Returned Data"; that needs to match what DataTables sends in the request.

On the server-side parse the request's "draw" param and send it back in the response along with search results.